# Ascii difference between two strings

Tags: string, bash, shell

Is there any way to find Ascii difference between two strings in shell scripting.First characters should be checked initially and If first letters are same it should check for second of both. Just like strcmp function of C.

strcmp returns difference of the ascii value of first unmatched characters. i.e strcmp("hello","world") is -15 and strcmp("hello","Hello") is 32. Hope you got it.

Comment: Need to be specific on the requirement. By "just like `strcmp` in C" do you mean you want it to return `-1` if string1 < string2, `0` if strings are equal, and `1` if string1 > string2?

Comment: strcmp returns difference in ascii characters. i.e strcmp("hello","world") is -15 and strcmp("hello","Hello") is 32. Hope you got it

Comment: Clearly we're all confused about what you're trying to do. Post some sample input and expected output to help us help you.

Comment: The standard C `strcmp` library call just returns `-1`, `0`, or `1` depending upon whether string1 is less, equal to, or greater. Where are you getting your `strcmp` from?

Comment: I have edited question. Standard library of C is returning ascii difference in case of strcmp. I have checked it.

Comment: Could you point to the manual page, please? I ran a test with `gcc` and it only gave `-1`, `0`, or `1`.

Comment: ohh iam doing gcc too. Mine is returning ascii difference. Version problem?

Comment: Perhaps. The manual page only stipulates that "a positive value" is returned if string1 > string2, and "a negative value" is returned if string1 < string2. It appears to be implementation dependent. Well, that's an interesting side-effect that I would not count on in C! But if that's what you're after in the shell, then that's the task.

Comment: strcmp() doesn't just return -1, 0, or 1, it returns the numeric difference between the first 2 characters. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strcmp.html. Not saying that's particularly more useful than just -1/0/1 but there y'go.

Comment: yup thats what is happening with my gcc. I guess this is a little tough job than directly using >,< or - kind of operators

Comment: @EdMorton funny mine doesn't work that way in `gcc 4.7.2`. I did a `strcmp("abc", "def")` and it yielded `-1`. A `strcmp("hello","Hello")` yielded `1`. If you read the sentence in that link carefully, in says: "*The sign of* a non-zero return value *shall be determined by the sign of* the difference between the values..." It doesn't say it will be equal to that difference. It only guarantees that the sign will be what you expect, nothing else.

Comment: @mbratch - yup, looks like you could interpret it that way. Ah C, the perfect choice of weapon for those who don't want feet....

Comment: Hmm...Mine is gcc 4.7.3. They must have changed it then !!

Comment: @EdMorton, the spec just says "The `strcmp` function returns an integer greater than, equal to, or less than zero, accordingly as the string pointed to by `s1` is greater than, equal to, or less than the string pointed to by `s2`."

Comment: @sjrocker, it's a behavior which is *consistent* with the `strcmp` definition but *not dictated* by it. It is even interesting and probably, in some cases, convenient. But I would not consider it standard behavior that can be relied upon portably (our comparative experiment has proven that). It's probably "convenient" behavior on the part of whoever touched the `strcmp` function in the library (why someone changed the venerable `strcmp` is anyone's guess...).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the difference between the ascii values of two characters like this:

```
(( $(printf %d \"$a) - $(printf %d \"$b)))
```

So this should work:

```sh
strcmp() {
  local diff
  for ((i=0; i<=${#1}; ++i)); do
    if ((diff=$(printf %d \""${1:i:1}") - $(printf %d \""${2:i:1}") ));
      then echo $diff; return
    fi
  done
  echo 0
}
```

You didn't specify what the value should be if one string is a prefix of the other; the above uses the trailing NUL character (0) of the shorter string to compute the difference.

Testing:

```
$ strcmp hello world
-15
$ strcmp hello Hello
32
$ strcmp abc def
-3
$ strcmp def abc
3
$ strcmp def dbc
3
$ strcmp def ddc
1
$ strcmp def dgc
-2
$ strcmp def dec
3
$ strcmp def de
102
$ strcmp de def
-102
$ strcmp def def
0
$ strcmp "a b c" "a bde"
-68
$ strcmp "a b c" "a b e"
-2
```

Answer (score 2):

In bash (since you tagged it):

```
$ cat tst.sh
function strcmp() {
    printf "%d\n" $(( $(printf "%d" "'${1:0:1}") - $(printf "%d" "'${2:0:1}")))
}

printf "strcmp(\"$1\",\"$2\") = %d\n" $(strcmp "$1" "$2")
$ ./tst.sh foo foo
strcmp("foo","foo") = 0
$ ./tst.sh foo bar
strcmp("foo","bar") = 4
$ ./tst.sh bar foo
strcmp("bar","foo") = -4
```

Comment: This also returns `0` for `foo` and `far` (even though the strings aren't equal), whereas the `strcmp` function he says he's using would return the value of `'o' - 'a'`.

Comment: Darn it! I'm not going to waste time doing it, but the OP can code the char-by-char comparison if he likes using the above method to get the numeric values of characters.

Comment: Anyways I wrote the correct code using printf only..Just wanted something to return Ascii Value. printf did the trick :)

Comment: Sounds like you're saying a lot of people wasted a lot of time trying to help you diff 2 strings when all you actually wanted was to convert a char to it's ASCII value. Right?

Answer (score 1):

Use `test` (here called within brackets) to do lexical comparison.

```
[ 'bar' '<' 'foo' ] # returns true
[ 'bar' '>' 'foo' ] # returns false
[ 'bar' = 'foo' ] # returns false
```

You can put together a small function which somewhat mimics C's `strcmp` function:

```
function strcmp {
    if [ $1 == $2 ]
    then
        return 0
    elif [ $1 '<' $2 ]
    then
        return 2
    fi
    return 1
}

strcmp foo bar
echo $?
```

Remember there are no negative return values, so you've got to choose unusual return values or  set a variable instead.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize that until I read your comments. Originally `strcmp` only defines whether a number is equal, larger or smaller zero, the exact value is implementation defined.

Comment: I am running my C code with gcc it is showing ascii difference.

Comment: That's gcc's implementation, others implementation might only return -1, 0, 1. So this answer is about the standard C library's definition. See my other answer with a totally different approach.

Answer (score 1):

Following function dos the work,

```
  strcmp()
  {
    arg1=$1
    len=${#arg1}
    arg2=$2
    len1=${#arg2}
    len1=$(($len1+1))
    len=$(($len+1))
    i=0
    # echo $len - $len1

    while [ $i -le $len ] || [ $i -le $len1 ];
    do
       tem1=${arg1:$i:1}
       tem2=${arg2:$i:1}
       # echo $tem1-$tem2; 
       val1=`echo $tem1 | tr -d "\n" | od -An -t dC`     
       val2=`echo $tem2 | tr -d "\n" | od -An -t dC`
       res=$(($val1-$val2))
       if [ $res -lt 0 ] ; then
         # echo "Less $res"
          break
       elif [ $res -gt 0 ] ; then
          #echo "Greater $res"
           break
       # else 
         #     echo "Equal"
       fi
       i=$(($i+1))
        # echo "i=$i"
    done
    echo $res  
  }






 echo $(strcmp "Zefaop" "Zefat")
```

Answer (score 0):

Howabout

```
$ diff  <(echo "stackoverflow" ) <(echo "stackowerflow")
1c1
< stackoverflow
---
> stackowerflow
```

or

```
$ cmp -bl <(echo "stackoverflow") <(echo "stackowerflow")
                  7 166 v    167 w
```

Or, to loop over all characters in a string:

```
#!/bin/bash

foo=string
for (( i=0; i<${#foo}; i++ )); do
  echo ${foo:$i:1}
done
```

output:

```
s
t
r
i
n
g
```

Comment: how to get ascii difference of first unmatched characters from this. Output of diff is unclear. Cmp is returning ascii somewhere in its output. I guess something need to be done on this output

Answer (score 0):

Some nasty people say PHP is nothing but a wrapper around C, so let's use that:

```
$ difference=$(php -r "echo strcmp('foo', 'far');")
$ echo $difference
14
```

PHP is installed on most systems or can be easily added. It is not defined that `strcmp`'s return values must be anything but equal, smaller or greater 1 -- so that code is not to regarded portable without further testing (eg., when running PHP compiled with other compilers than gcc).

Comment: php not found it is showing for me. And I guess it is using standard strcmp internally. Any other way around?

Comment: Then install it, shouldn't be more than a single line and a few seconds on linux systems. ;) If not, you've got to write everything yourself.

Comment: Actually installing anything extra is not allowed here as I have to test it in other user's shell loaded with basic functionalities. Anyways thanks. I guess I have to implement it by myself.

Comment: Will be most safe; as you could read in the other comments you cannot even trust in all gcc versions having this semantics.

Comment: And the funny thing is, when I run `php -r "echo strcmp('foo', 'far');"` I get `1`. :)

Comment: A very good reason not to trust in any undefined `strcmp` behavior. :)